# How to use Microsoft.Update.Session() in powershell windows 7?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, updates

I want to export the update history(installed KB) list from Windows.
To Windows 10, I found the code under blow:

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()) | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path D:\$env:computername+KB.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However, I can't use it under Windows 7, because of some code error.

Does anyone know how to repair the code to run under Windows 7 ?
or have any other way to get the installed KB list ?

Comment: What is the "some code error"

Answer (score 0):

From a quick Google search DISM is available for Window 7 as well.  It can output in a list format.

If you open a PowerShell windows as Administrator, you can run:

```
PS C:\image_build> dism /format:Table /online /Get-Packages

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22000.653

Image Version: 10.0.22000.978

Packages listing:


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ---------- | --------------- | ------------------
Package Identity                                                                                     | State      | Release Type    | Install Time
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ---------- | --------------- | ------------------
Microsoft-OneCore-ApplicationModel-Sync-Desktop-FOD-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.22000.675   | Superseded | OnDemand Pack   | 12/05/2022 3:45 AM
Microsoft-OneCore-ApplicationModel-Sync-Desktop-FOD-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.22000.918   | Installed  
....
/truncated/
....
```

I'm not sure if DISM comes with Windows 7 by default.  You may need to download and/or enable it.

> **NOTE:** The command and output above are from Windows 11 and not Windows 7.